# I have a table in bootstrap - how can I add a column that contains remove button for selected row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a table in bootstrap, basically it contains different columns and rows, e.g.:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">4</td>
        <td class="center">X</td>
        <td class="center">Remove</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even gradeC">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">5</td>
        <td class="center">C</td>
        <td class="center">Remove</td>
    </tr>
    (...)
```

So far the last column contains static 'Remove' string. Is there a way of dynamically removing the row when the user hits the remove link there?

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyw6kajm/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can wrap your **Remove** in last `td` inside an anchor tag with some class name given to it, say `remove` and write a `click event` to that class.

Ex:

**HTML**

```
<tr class="odd gradeA">
     <td>Trident</td>
     <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
     <td>Win 95+</td>
     <td class="center">5.5</td>
     <td class="center">A</td>
     <td class="center"><a class='remove' href="#">Remove</a></td> <!--wrap in anchor tag-->
</tr>
<tr class="even gradeA">
     <td>Trident</td>
     <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
     <td>Win 98+</td>
     <td class="center">6</td>
     <td class="center">A</td>
     <td class="center"><a class='remove' href="#">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
$('.remove').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove(); //remove its root parent tr using closest
});
```

if the contents are dynamically added you can do `event delegation` as below:

```
$("#dataTables-example").on('click','.remove',function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove(); //remove its root parent tr using closest
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fyw6kajm/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can have delegated click event on last td of row or the row that contains text remove along with `.closest()` and `.remove()` for traversing to closest row and removing it respectively:

```
$('body').on('click','td:contains(Remove)',function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u10rrew8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Make the buttons.

```js
$("#trigger-overlay2").click(function() {
   // $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".overlay-boxify2").toggleClass("open");
   });
$(document).on('click','.tr_remove',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

```css
.overlay-boxify, .overlay-boxify2 {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
}
.overlay-boxify.open, .overlay-boxify2.open  {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
 z-index:9999;
}

.overlay2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/grid.png);
    background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.95);
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="trigger-overlay2" href="#contact">Trigger!</a>
<div class="overlay2 overlay-boxify2">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  
    <div class="tos-logo-contact">
     <img src="../img/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Location</th>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Time</th>
                                            <th>Duration</th>
                                            <th>Content</th>
                                            <th>Remove</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                            <td>Trident</td>
                                            <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
                                            <td>Win 95+</td>
                                            <td class="center">4</td>
                                            <td class="center">X</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="even gradeC">
                                            <td>Trident</td>
                                            <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
                                            <td>Win 95+</td>
                                            <td class="center">5</td>
                                            <td class="center">C</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="odd gradeA">
                                            <td>Trident</td>
                                            <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
                                            <td>Win 95+</td>
                                            <td class="center">5.5</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="even gradeA">
                                            <td>Trident</td>
                                            <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
                                            <td>Win 98+</td>
                                            <td class="center">6</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="odd gradeA">
                                            <td>Trident</td>
                                            <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
                                            <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
                                            <td class="center">7</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="even gradeA">
                                            <td>Trident</td>
                                            <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
                                            <td>Win XP</td>
                                            <td class="center">6</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
                                            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.7</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
                                            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.8</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
                                            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.8</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
                                            <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.9</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Camino 1.0</td>
                                            <td>OSX.2+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.8</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Camino 1.5</td>
                                            <td>OSX.3+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.8</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
                                            <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.7</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
                                            <td>Win 98SE+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.7</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
                                            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.8</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
                                            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
                                            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.1</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
                                            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.2</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td>Gecko</td>
                                            <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
                                            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                                            <td class="center">1.3</td>
                                            <td class="center">A</td>
                                            <td class="center tr_remove">Remove</td>
                                        </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>       
      </div>
                    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This removes the entire tr/row-element and its children, but you should assign a class to your remove button that is specific to this function, e.g. js_remove_row. Because this handle: "tr > td:last-child" could target other stuff if you change your table. Notice the js-prefix which lets you know that this class is a javascript-handler and not used for styling. I also use $(document).on... because if doesn't break if you ajax-load part of your page or table, document is always there and you don't have to reset the handler if reloading your content.

This works:

```
$(document).on("click", "tr > td:last-child", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove(); 
});
```

This is better:

```
<td class="center js_remove_row">Remove</td>

$(document).on("click", ".js_remove_row", function() {
      $(this).parent().remove(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add class to call click event on remove td and add click event to remove like below:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyw6kajm/3/)

```
<td class="center removetd">Remove</td>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".removetd").click(function(){
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching `click` event to `tr` element , using `event.target` , `Node.textContent` , calling `$(this).remove()` if `event.target` text is "Remove"

```js
$("tr").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.textContent === "Remove") $(this).remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">4</td>
        <td class="center">X</td>
        <td class="center">Remove</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even gradeC">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">5</td>
        <td class="center">C</td>
        <td class="center">Remove</td>
    </tr>
    (...)
  </table>
```